# Power apps canvas: Attaching a collection to a existing SharePoint item

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

I am creating a Power Apps Canvas app. In this app I have a form that creates an item in a SharePoint list using a button: OnSelect "SubmitForm(Form1)". this creates the item but I want to also attach the consents of a table. The table data is stored in a collection and I want the data in the collection added to the item the form just created. I have an empty column in the SharePoint side called "Table Data" and I need to put the collection data into that items column

I have tried using the patch function but I'm not sure how to select the item the form just created. I can select the right SharePoint list but I'm not sure how to select the item.

Answer (score 0):

To reference the item created with Form1, you can use `Form1.LastSubmit`.

To attach tabular data to your SP record, I guess you have 3 options:

1. Use the JSON() function to jsonify your data. This can then be stored as text in SharePoint. You cannot read this back into PowerApps, but you can use the json in Power Automate.
2. You can come up with some sort of separator and save your results as delimited text. This is less preferable, but can be reused to some extent in Power Apps.
3. If your data structure allows that, you can create a 1-N relationship with a second table to store the tabular data with external keys pointing to your form submission.

Answer (score 0):

You have two basic options.

First, as @mmikesy90 wrote, you can use Form1.LastSubmit to reference the entire item you just created (i.e., a record).  You can then use whatever the unique identifier for your list is.  If you have an id column, it would be like this:

```
SubmitForm(Form1);
Patch(SharePointListName, LookUp(SharePointListName, id = Form1.LastSubmit.id), {'Table Data': JSON(TableRecordYouWantToAddToItem)});
```

This assumes you want to add the table data as JSON, which means your sharepoint column is a Single line text column.

As a note, you can pull this back in to PowerApps with the [ParseJSON() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-parsejson), but it is messy to say the least.

The second option works if you are inputting anything into the form that is a unique identifier.  For instance, if you are creating a SharePoint list of people, and you know that you will only ever have one list item per person, and you are using their email address (or, for example, a user id) as a unique identifier, you could do this:

```
Set(tempUniqueId, emailAddressDataCardInForm.Update);
SubmitForm(Form1);
Patch(SharePointListName, LookUp(SharePointListName, 'email address' = tempUniqueId), {'Table Data': JSON(TableRecordYouWantToAddToItem)});
```

There are probably a few subtle differences between these two approaches.  One is that, Form1.LastSubmit returns the value of the last record that was SUCCESSFULLY submitted in the current session.  So, if the SubmitForm fails, you will not get the current form info.  That could be good because you do not want to try to send the TableData if the main form was not successsful.  On the other hand, I do not remember what happens to Form1.LastSubmit if the user successfully submits an entry AND THEN tries a different one that fails.  In other words, is it possible that Form1.LastSubmit will incorrectly return an older entry?

**For either option, I would suggest that you move the Patch from the OnSubmit button to the Form's OnSuccess field.  That way, it will only try to patch in the Table Data if the form has successfully submitted to the SharePoint List.
If you do, either of the methods I wrote will still work.**